# Как передать параметры в функцию, которая находится в обработчике событий?

Tags: javascript

Например:

```
var doSomething = function (a, b, c) { 
  alert(a + b + c) 
}

button.addEventListener('click', doSomething(1, 2, 3));
```

https://jsbin.com/vevifefano/edit?html,js,output

p.s. функция срабатывает сразу после загрузки страницы. как тогда быть?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/?html,output - вот здесь можно проверить. А по сути, код выполниться, но только не после клика, а сразу, при добавлении обработчика

Comment: @Дмытрык точняк) проверил, функция запускается, сразу после загрузки страницы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случаи, вы передаете вызовов функции: `doSomething(1, 2, 3)`, которая вернет `undefined`.

> button.addEventListener('click', doSomething(1, 2, 3));

Вы можете воспользоваться встроенным методом `bind`.

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");

let doSomething = function (a, b, c) { 
  alert(a + b + c) 
}

button.addEventListener('click', doSomething.bind(null, 1, 2, 3));
```

```html
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Или замыкание.

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");

let doSomething = function (a, b, c) {
  return function f() {
    alert(a + b + c);
  }
}

let doSomethingSecond = (a,b,c) => f => alert(a + b + c); //Стрелочная функция

button.addEventListener('click', doSomething(1, 2, 3));
```

```html
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Сохранить возможность использовать `event` и передавать параметры вам поможет `Hight order function`

```js
const foo = (a,b,c) => event => console.log(a,b,c)

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', foo(1,2,3))
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```